# Insertion point vanishes in Word 365 after inserting a new page

Tags: microsoft-word, office365

Has anybody else had this problem:

[image: Gif of problem]

If I click with the I-beam after adding a new page, I can't see where the mouse pointer is (although if I type it reassuringly reappears). I'm on build 2106 of Office 365, if that helps, and this is a new problem (I've been a power Word user for many years, and never seen this before).

Comment: On my Word (Version 2016, Bulid 14131.20320), if I insert a page break on a new blank document directly, without pressing Enter key, the cursor could not be found on new page, I need to double click, then the cursor could be shown again.

Comment: I don't think this quite does the same thing.  When you double-click it tells Word that you want to insert text at this point.  Unless this is at the top left of the page, you run the risk of inserting carriage returns and tab characters too.

Comment: I always turn this "click-and-type feature" *off* as soon as I install Word. And, **yes, I am seeing the same thing with the insertion point marker disappearing** until I start typing. (same build) I seldom insert page breaks but rather use page-break-before paragraph formatting in a heading style. The disappearing insertion point is definitely not happening in Word 2010. I would classify this as a bug. Feedback to MS: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/send-feedback-to-ms-developers/506e7654-8ced-405b-911e-c58d8f253069

Comment: While you and I can only use the feedback mechanism, Word MVPs may be able to make direct contact with the product team. I've posted this as a discussion on the Microsoft Community Answers site with the .gif that I put into your question. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_2016/disappearing-insertion-point-after-page-break/5851eb58-8aeb-4411-a09f-db2bffd957ee

Comment: Thanks Charles.  It wasn't a bug in Word 365 six months ago either!